# passing session variable in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I have the modal where I am processing the data in the modal and then I need to store 1 value and pass it to the next page but then for some reason it is not working.

My modal code :- I have the variable `$doctorName` already set

```
session(['doctorName' => $doctorName]);
```

My view file

```
<div class="col-sm-12 row2">
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>Second Opinion from
                    <br /><span id="dr_Name"></span></p>
            </td>
            {{ session('doctorName') }}
            <td align="right">
                <p>INR 3000/-</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Im not sure, if global helper works in view too, try `{{ Session::get('doctorName') }}`

Comment: Wait, I'm confused, isn't a modal a client side concept?

Comment: @Autista_z .. not working

Answer (score 0):

Try `{!! session('doctorName') !!}` instead of `{{ session('doctorName') }}`

Answer (score 0):

Do you open new view after modal? Maybe you need:

return view('someview')->with('doctorName');

Comment: I am not calling the view directly from the modal .. I'm redirecting back to the controller and then calling the view..

Comment: did you use with('doctorName');?